# Bootstrap 4 dropdown opens in navbar and increases the navbar height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am developing a laravel app. I need two navbars, number Two below number One, one containing logo and logout link, another containing all the links.

I have achieved the look but the dropdown  of the logout link is opening in navbar One resulting in increase in the height of the navbar each time the dropdown is toggled.

Images -

[image: Dropdown not toggled]

[image: Dropdown toggled]

Here is my code -

```
<div id="header-main">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/accounts.png') }}" height="50px">
            </a>
            @auth
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                        {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">{{ __('Logout') }}</a>
                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                @csrf
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
            @endauth
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @guest
                    <li class="nav-item @if(Route::current()->getName() == 'login') active @endif">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> {{ __('Login') }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <li class="nav-item @if(Route::current()->getName() == 'register') active @endif">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> {{ __('Register') }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @else
                    <li class="nav-item @if(Route::current()->getName() == 'home') active @endif">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('home') }}"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> {{ __('Home') }}</a>
                    </li>
                @endguest
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Somebody help me.

Comment: The issue you have is with CSS, not with Laravel. Will be better to add `css` tag to the question

Comment: @ArmKh Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position-absolute` on the dropdown menu...

```
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
             <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                     username<span class="caret"></span>
             </a>
             <div class="dropdown-menu position-absolute dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" >Logout</a>
                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;"> @csrf </form>
             </div>
      </li>
```

https://codeply.com/p/fHoKygnLv7